# Radical additive expression in relation to partial derivative.

Tags: partial-derivative, radicals

I am learning the partial derivative and I am stuck on how to proceed with the following expression.

`z = √(4 - x^2 - y^2)`

the expressions I need to find are `Δ_x z,Δ_y z and Δz`, which are are intersections in the plane x,y,z,  where
`Δ_x z = f(x+Δx,y) - f(x,y)
 Δ_y z = f(x,y+Δy) - f(x,y)
 Δz = f(x+Δx,y+Δy) - f(x,y)`

I have been out of school for a few years now and I can't find any explanations on how to simplify addition expression in a radical such as the expresion z above and this is blocking me.

My first instinct would be to leave the expression complete (for example, `Δ_x z = √(4 - (x+Δx)^2 - y^2) - √(4 - x^2 - y^2)`, but in my previous examples, the  `-f(x,y)` part of the expressions would simplify the non-delta expressions and that confuses me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to compute the partial derivative wrt $x$ of $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$, given by $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{4-(x+\Delta x)^2-y^2} - \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}{\Delta x}$$, a good trick is to multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate expression $\sqrt{4-(x+\Delta x)^2-y^2} + \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and simplify.  This will eliminate the square roots.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, to multiply by the conjugate expression, I need to multiply it on denominator and numerator (to multiply by 1), so I will be left with the conjugate at the denominator, no?

edit : I misread a little bit here. But still, the conjugate expression will still be present at the denominator and I am not sure how to go from there neither.

Comment: After multiplying numerator and denominator, you can distribute and should be able to cancel out a $\Delta x$.

Comment: I will still be stuck with    ${2x}{/}{(}{\sqrt{4-(x+\Delta x)^2-y^2} +\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}{)}$ and I still have the same issue as when I started.
edit: sorry for the edits, begginer mathjax

Comment: Exactly !  In the limit as $\Delta x$ goes to zero, this becomes $\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}$

Comment: which is the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to apply the limit with my answer (and I didn't derive properly as well).